# Vue2 + Airtable - How can I sort a v-for loop so its not in a random order?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli, airtable

I have a problem I can’t seem to solve with Airtable and Vue2 CLI and wondered if anyone could help?

I have set up a base and am using a Vue for loop to iterate through a list of objects. Although my loop works, and renders to the browser correctly, the order of the objects are completely random. I have tried different methods to try and get them in the same order, so that they match the order in the Airtable base but nothing seems to work. My code is as follows:

In my Vue Component;

```
<div class="timeline-wrapper" v-for="record in records" v-bind:key="record.Title">
    <h2>{{ record['fields']['Title'] }}</h2>
</div>
```

Then in the script of the component I have;

```
import axios from 'axios';
axios({
    url: 'https://api.airtable.com/v0/app123456789/',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer key123456789'
    }
}).then((res) => {
    res.data.records
});
export default {
    props: [
        'columns'
    ],
    data() {
        return {
            apiUrl: 'https://api.airtable.com/v0/',
            apiKey: 'key123456789',
            base: 'app123456789/NameOfBase',
            records: [
            ]
        };
    },
    mounted() {
        this.getData();
    },
    methods: {
        getData: function() {
            axios({
                url: this.apiUrl + this.base,
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.apiKey}`
                }
            }).then((res) => {
                this.records = res.data.records;
            });
        }
    }
};
```

The order in the based on Airtable is as in the attached image;

[image: Airtable Base]

However, this prints, B, D, A, C in the browser.

Console;
[image]

Any help welcome.

Comment: Can we see a console log of (a few of) `res.data.records`?  Seems straight-forward to apply a sort when assigning to `this.records`

Comment: As in ```console.log(res.data.records);```